# how do I get the process list in Python?

Tags: python, unix, kill, ps, processlist

How do I get a process list of all running processes from Python, on Unix, containing then name of the command/process and process id, so I can filter and kill processes.

Comment: Are you filtering for anything specific in the process name? or just filtering for the process ids that match the process name?

Comment: I need to match up some streaming session in Darwin Streaming Server that doesn't have any current listeners, with the process providing the stream.
Some one mentioned pgrep/pkill which also would be useful, but I think I'll use krawyoti and do os.kill from python, I'm just more comfortable writing python code then using shell commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux, the easiest solution is probably to use the external `ps` command:

```
>>> import os
>>> data = [(int(p), c) for p, c in [x.rstrip('\n').split(' ', 1) \
...        for x in os.popen('ps h -eo pid:1,command')]]
```

On other systems you might have to change the options to `ps`.

Still, you might want to run `man` on `pgrep` and `pkill`.

Comment: pgrep/pkill looks like a good solution for what I need (at least this time).
I've always missed a built in ps function in Python, so that's part of the reason I posted this question. 
Cheers

Comment: os.popen is deprecated. Use the subprocess module.

Comment: Huh, this is interesting. It's worth a question on its own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098257

Answer (score 32):

The right portable solution in Python is using [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil). You have different APIs to interact with PIDs:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.pids()
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, ..., 32498]
>>> psutil.pid_exists(32498)
True
>>> p = psutil.Process(32498)
>>> p.name()
'python'
>>> p.cmdline()
['python', 'script.py']
>>> p.terminate()
>>> p.wait()
```

...and if you want to "search and kill":

```
for p in psutil.process_iter():
    if 'nginx' in p.name() or 'nginx' in ' '.join(p.cmdline()):
        p.terminate()
        p.wait()
```

Answer (score 12):

On Linux, with a suitably recent Python which includes the `subprocess` module:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(['ps', '-eo' ,'pid,args'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, notused = process.communicate()
for line in stdout.splitlines():
    pid, cmdline = line.split(' ', 1)
    #Do whatever filtering and processing is needed
```

You may need to tweak the ps command slightly depending on your exact needs.

Comment: What does "suitably recent Python" mean ? 2.7 ? 3.0 ? 3.8 ?

Comment: @Itération122442 it means recent enough to contain the `subprocess` module - so 2.4-2.7, 3.5+.

Answer (score 0):

Install psutil:

```
$pip install psutil
```

Import psutil:

```
>>> import psutil
```

Define list where process list is to be saved:

```
>>> processlist=list()
```

Append processes in list:

```
>>> for process in psutil.process_iter():
        processlist.append(process.name())
```

Get Process list:

```
>>> print(processlist)
```

Full code:

```
import psutil
processlist=list()
for process in psutil.process_iter():
    processlist.append(process.name())
print(processlist)
```

Answer (score -10):

Why Python?
You can directly use [`killall`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/killall.1.html) on the process name.

Comment: he said he would filter and then kill

Comment: Good observation, but why filter the `ps` output for the command name, gather process id values and then kill, when the `killall` does it for you?

Comment: because I need to match up the processes with other data.

Comment: I am retaining this answer because it highlights the need for a ithin-python solution. The question has no need for the `kill` part; it can be simply, `how do I get the process list in Python?`