# Python subprocess in .exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, network-programming, subprocess

I'm creating a python script that will copy files and folder over the network. it's cross-platform so I make an .exe file using ***cx_freeze***

I used Popen method of the subprocess module

if I run ***.py*** file it is running as expected but when i create ***.exe*** subprocess is not created in the system

I've gone through all documentation of subprocess module but I didn't find any solution

everything else (I am using Tkinter that also works fine) is working in the .exe accept subprocess.

any idea how can I call subprocess in .exe.file ??

***This file is calling another .py file***

```
def start_scheduler_action(self, scheduler_id, scheduler_name, list_index):
       scheduler_detail=db.get_scheduler_detail_using_id(scheduler_id)
        for detail in scheduler_detail:
            source_path=detail[2]
        if not os.path.exists(source_path):
            showerror("Invalid Path","Please select valid path", parent=self.new_frame)
            return

        self.forms.new_scheduler.start_scheduler_button.destroy()

        #Create stop scheduler button
        if getattr(self.forms.new_scheduler, "stop_scheduler_button", None)==None:

            self.forms.new_scheduler.stop_scheduler_button = tk.Button(self.new_frame, text='Stop scheduler', width=10, command=lambda:self.stop_scheduler_action(scheduler_id, scheduler_name, list_index))
            self.forms.new_scheduler.stop_scheduler_button.grid(row=11, column=1, sticky=E, pady=10, padx=1)

        scheduler_id=str(scheduler_id)

        # Get python paths
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            proc = subprocess.Popen(['where', "python"], env=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        else:
            proc = subprocess.Popen(['which', "python"], env=None,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        out, err = proc.communicate()

        if err or not out:
            showerror("", "Python not found", parent=self.new_frame)

        else:

            try:
                paths = out.split(os.pathsep)

                # Create python path
                python_path = (paths[len(paths) - 1]).split('\n')[0]

                cmd = os.path.realpath('scheduler.py')
                #cmd='scheduler.py'

                if sys.platform == "win32":
                    python_path=python_path.splitlines()

                else:
                    python_path=python_path

                # Run the scheduler file using scheduler id

                proc = subprocess.Popen([python_path, cmd, scheduler_id], env=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


                message="Started the scheduler : %s" %(scheduler_name)
                showinfo("", message, parent=self.new_frame)

                #Add process id to scheduler table
                process_id=proc.pid
                #showinfo("pid", process_id, parent=self.new_frame)
                def get_process_id(name):
                    child = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', '-f', name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
                    response = child.communicate()[0]
                    return [int(pid) for pid in response.split()]

                print(get_process_id(scheduler_name))

                # Add the process id in database
                self.db.add_process_id(scheduler_id, process_id)

                # Add the is_running status in database
                self.db.add_status(scheduler_id)

            except Exception as e:

                showerror("", e)
```

***And this file is called:***

```
def scheduler_copy():

    date= strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H %M %S", localtime())
    logFile = scheduler_name + "_"+scheduler_id+"_"+ date+".log"
    #file_obj=open(logFile, 'w')

    # Call __init__ method of xcopy file 
    xcopy=XCopy(connection_ip, username , password, client_name, server_name, domain_name)
    check=xcopy.connect()

    # Cretae a log file for scheduler
    file_obj=open(logFile, 'w')

    if check is False:

        file_obj.write("Problem in connection..Please check connection..!!")
        return

    scheduler_next_run=schedule.next_run()
    scheduler_next_run="Next run at: " +str(scheduler_next_run)

    # If checkbox_value selected copy all the file to new directory
    if checkbox_value==1:
        new_destination_path=xcopy.create_backup_directory(share_folder, destination_path, date)
    else:
        new_destination_path=destination_path

    # Call backup method for coping data from source to destination
    try:
        xcopy.backup(share_folder, source_path, new_destination_path, file_obj, exclude)
        file_obj.write("Scheduler completed successfully..\n")

    except Exception as e:

        # Write the error message of the scheduler to log file
        file_obj.write("Scheduler failed to copy all data..\nProblem in connection..Please check connection..!!\n")
        # #file_obj.write("Error while scheduling")
        # return

    # Write the details of scheduler to log file
    file_obj.write("Total skipped unmodified file:")
    file_obj.write(str(xcopy.skipped_unmodified_count))
    file_obj.write("\n")
    file_obj.write("Total skipped file:")
    file_obj.write(str(xcopy.skipped_file))
    file_obj.write("\n")
    file_obj.write("Total copied file:")
    file_obj.write(str(xcopy.copy_count))
    file_obj.write("\n")
    file_obj.write("Total skipped folder:")
    file_obj.write(str(xcopy.skipped_folder))
    file_obj.write("\n")
    # file_obj.write(scheduler_next_run)
    file_obj.close()
```

Comment: Do you mean that the subprocess is not executed? Is there an error? Possibly to do with paths - what are you trying to run as the subprocess?

Comment: Is the exe working fine without trying it with the Python code ? Maybe some parameters were absent so process failed to start.

Comment: nothing with the path and also no error is shown. it's just not calling a subprocess.

Comment: I'm using tkinter. in exe all tkinter functinality is working fine @Rockybilly

Comment: Something point is missing, you create an `exe` but need permission for accessing system resources. How to suppressed `UAC` rule ?

Comment: So the subprocess is not started. Does your code that attempts to start the subprocess check the return value and log it? How are you starting the subprocess? To get further help you will probably need to post the relevant code.

Comment: i've added the code you can check it. *python_path, cmd and id* together create a command that runs in terminal or cmd in windows

Comment: What version of Python is being used? please include minor version number.

Comment: im using 2.7.6 but i also tried in 3.4.6

Comment: Possible to get a git repo for testing?

Comment: No @TarunLalwani it's a privet project

Comment: I just need a template project to debug, so it can have just subprocess call to any windows command and as close as possible to the requirements files and everything you use. Not asking for full project

Comment: i've added the code but it's not full and it gives only basic information @TarunLalwani

Comment: I think your issue might be exe without a console. Do you get a console also when you launch the code? If you only get a GUI then it may be possible that there is no stdout at all, in that case you should not use `proc = subprocess.Popen(['where', "python"], env=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`, you should rather use `proc = subprocess.Popen(['where', "python"], env=None, stdout=filehandle)`. The `filehandle` will be a file you just opened using `open` or `io.open`. See if changing that helps

Comment: actually, I don't need the console because the file is just opening and running in the background i also tried to get the process id which I'm getting and that process id is correct so. i think the file is called and stops too. let me try what you suggest.

Comment: i tried what you suggested and i got python path which i think we're expecting  @TarunLalwani

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156103/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-manan-kalariya).

Comment: Ok, to summarize the problem it appears the cx_Freeze is altering the behavior of Subprocess. It seems that is has been reported in other [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151539/subprocess-popen-behavior-after-cx-freeze) that depending on your cx_Freeze configuration you will have problems getting stdout and also this may cause the child processes will fail. I recommend implementing the solution given (notice the comments say you must set the encoding as well) and reporting back the result

Comment: i tried the solution given in the thread but my program stops when it calls `return_code = process.wait()` and can't able to go further @LiamKelly

Comment: @manan_kalariya can you see the temporary file referenced in the example code being created? can you open it and see valid text? I want to see if the process is actually running. If there is a valid text, than it ran and it is just not closing, which can be *crudely* fixed with sending an interrupt.

Comment: no, the file is not creating it just pops up and immediately gone from the system. so at the end, I've come with a different solution I created a scheduler file in windows which will do my work and wire a .bash file which ultimately works together to run my .py file in background.

Comment: you obviously have a main file you are turning to exe using cx_Freeze, which the base should be win32, your second file (to be the subprocess) could then be turned to exe using `base=None` and then set flags so that the console is suppressed (not visible) that way cx_Freeze should not be messing with/redirecting and output

Answer (score 4):

There is some awkwardness in your source code, but I won't spend time on that.  For instance, if you want to find the *source_path*, it's better to use a `for` loop with `break`/`else`:

```
for detail in scheduler_detail:
    source_path = detail[2]
    break  # found
else:
    # not found: raise an exception
    ...
```

Some advice:

- Try to separate the user interface code and the sub-processing, avoid mixing the two.
- Use exceptions and exception handlers.
- If you want portable code: avoid system call (there are no `pgrep` on Windows).

---

Since your application is packaged in a virtualenv (I make the assumption cx_freeze does this kind of thing), you have no access to the system-wide Python. You even don't have that on Windows. So you need to use the packaged Python (this is a best practice anyway).

If you want to call a Python script like a subprocess, that means you have two packaged applications: you need to create an `exe` for the main application **and** for the `scheduler.py` script. But, that's not easy to communicate with it.

Another solution is to use `multiprocessing` to spawn a new Python process. Since you don't want to wait for the end of processing (which may be long), you need to create daemon processes. The way to do that is explained in the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class) module.

Basically:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()

    # let it live and die, don't call: `p.join()`
    time.sleep(1)
```

Of course, we need to adapt that with your problem.

Here is how I would do that (I removed UI-related code for clarity):

```
import scheduler


class SchedulerError(Exception):
    pass


class YourClass(object):
    def start_scheduler_action(self, scheduler_id, scheduler_name, list_index):
        scheduler_detail = db.get_scheduler_detail_using_id(scheduler_id)
        for detail in scheduler_detail:
            source_path = detail[2]
            break
        else:
            raise SchedulerError("Invalid Path", "Missing source path", parent=self.new_frame)

        if not os.path.exists(source_path):
            raise SchedulerError("Invalid Path", "Please select valid path", parent=self.new_frame)

        p = Process(target=scheduler.scheduler_copy, args=('source_path',))
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

        self.db.add_process_id(scheduler_id, p.pid)
```

To check if your process is still running, I recommend you to use [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil). It's really a great tool!

You can define your `scheduler.py` script like that:

```
def scheduler_copy(source_path):
    ...
```

---

**Multiprocessing vs Threading Python**

Quoting this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3044626/1513933

> The `threading` module uses threads, the `multiprocessing` module uses processes. The difference is that threads run in the same memory space, while processes have separate memory. This makes it a bit harder to share objects between processes with multiprocessing. Since threads use the same memory, precautions have to be taken or two threads will write to the same memory at the same time. This is what the global interpreter lock is for.

Here, the advantage of multiprocessing over multithreading is that you can kill (or terminate) a process; you can't kill a thread. You may need psutil for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact solution you are looking for, but following suggestion should be preferred for two reasons.

1. These are more pythonic way
2. `subprocess` is slightly expensive

#### Suggestions you can consider

1. Don't use subprocess for fetching system path. Try check `os.getenv('PATH')` to get env variable & try to find if python is in the path. For windows, one has to manually add Python path or else you can directly check in `Program Files` I guess
2. For checking process ID's you can try `psutils`. A wonderful answer is provided here at [how do I get the process list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091327/how-do-i-get-the-process-list-in-python)
3. Calling another script from a python script. This does not look cool. Not bad, but I would not prefer this at all.
4. In above code, line - `if sys.platform == "win32":` has same value in `if` and `else` condition ==> you dont need a conditional statement here.

You wrote pretty fine working code to tell you. Keep Coding!

Comment: You can get the current Python path with `sys.executable`. The current OS may have no installed Python executable. You must run the Python from the `exe` environment, usually a virtualenv.

Comment: cool. thanks for sharing. I was thinking once its a `exe`, it won't need python. Am I wrong?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run a subprocess in an exe file, then you can use

```
import subprocess

program=('example')
arguments=('/command')
subprocess.call([program, arguments])
```

Comment: Instead of using a subprocess you can create a fuction, and put the code in the function. you can call the fuction in the main program. This is a better option.

Comment: do you think !!! I want is as a new process because im creating multi-processing app

Comment: If you want an multiprocessing , here is an example.                      
 import multiprocessing
mport time
def a():
    while True:
        print (1)
##        time.sleep(3)

def d():
     while True:
        print(0)
        time.sleep(3)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='p1', target=a)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(name='p', target=d)
   p1.start()
    p.start()